# how to align text using \begin{itemize}

Tags: itemize

I'm trying to create a short list of items with a brief description on right side. I'm using the \begin{itemize}[label={}] environment and the \hspace*[2cm] command for alignment, but i can't get the text aligned. Could someone give me any suggestion?

**my code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}

\begin{document}
    As variáveis de entrada e de saída e os parâmetros de entrada da mesma são os seguintes:
    
    \begin{itemize}[label={}]
        \item $rl$ \tab[2cm] resistência total da LT
        \item $xl$ \tab[2cm] reatância total da LT
        \item $hf$ \tab[2cm] distância (em km) até o ponto de ocorrência do defeito;
        \item $c0$ \tab[2cm] total de ciclos observados antes da ocorrência do defeito;
        \item $c1$ \tab[2cm] total de ciclos observados durante a primeira falta;
        \item $c2$ \tab[2cm] total de ciclos correspondentes ao tempo morto;
        \item $c3$ \tab[2cm] total de ciclos observados durante a segunda falta;
    \end{itemize}
    \par
    \begin{itemize}[label={}]
        \item filename \tab[2cm] nome do arquivo de pontos da curva de saturação do TC simulado;
        \item burden   \tab[2cm] vetor linha ($2 \times 1$) com a resistência e reatância do \textit{burden} do TC;
        \item ang      \tab[2cm] vetor linha ($2 \times 1$) com os ângulos de incidência da $1^a$ e $2^a$ faltas;
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

**result**

[image]

**I would like my result to be this (ms-word):**

[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is use the `eqlist` package. If the default separation of labels is not enough, try with some like  `\begin{eqlist}[\labelsep2em]` or use `\setlength\labelsep{2em}` in the preamble.

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eqlist}
\begin{document}
 As variáveis de entrada e de saída e os parâmetros de entrada da mesma são os seguintes:
 \begin{eqlist}
 \item[$rl$] resistência total da LT
 \item[$xl$] reatância total da LT
 \item[$hf$] distância (em km) até o ponto de ocorrência do defeito;
 \item[$c0$] total de ciclos observados antes da ocorrência do defeito;
 \item[$c1$] total de ciclos observados durante a primeira falta;
 \item[$c2$] total de ciclos correspondentes ao tempo morto;
 \item[$c3$] total de ciclos observados durante a segunda falta;
 \item[filename] nome do arquivo de pontos da curva de saturação do TC simulado;
 \item[burden] vetor linha ($2 \times 1$) com a resistência e reatância do \textit{burden} do TC;
 \item[ang] vetor linha ($2 \times 1$) com os ângulos de incidência da $1^a$ e $2^a$ faltas;
\end{eqlist}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can also use  the `desclist` package:

```
% In preamble:
\usepackage{desclist}
% In document environment
\begin{desclist}{}{}[xxxxxxxxxxx]
\item[$rl$] resistência  ....
\end{desclist}
```

Where the optional parameter `xxxxxxxxxxx` is text to use as largest label model to calculate the proper hang indent of the items. The two empty mandatory arguments (`{}{}`)are needed only in case that you want some prefix-sufix in the labels, usually to obtained a special format, e.g, `{\em}{\dotfill}`:

> [image: mwe]

Another is `expdlist` package that allow optional arguments to the standard description environment so you can use:

```
\begin{description}[\setlabelphantom{a very long label}]
```

In your example  the results is not very nice because labels in math mode cannot take the default bold font. But you can `\setlabelstyle`. Run `texdoc expdlist` for more information.

Or without packages and without environment, with a custom pseudoitem with one optional argument to change the default item label width (3em) to something else:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand\ditem[2][3em]{\par\medskip\noindent\hangindent#1\makebox[#1][l]{#2}}
\begin{document}
As variáveis de entrada e de saída e os parâmetros de entrada da mesma são os seguintes:
\ditem{$rl$} resistência total da LT
\ditem{$xl$} reatância total da LT
\ditem{$hf$} distância (em km) até o ponto de ocorrência do defeito;
\ditem{$c0$} total de ciclos observados antes da ocorrência do defeito;
\ditem{$c1$} total de ciclos observados durante a primeira falta;
\ditem{$c2$} total de ciclos correspondentes ao tempo morto;
\ditem{$c3$} total de ciclos observados durante a segunda falta;
\ditem[5em]{filename}  nome do arquivo de pontos da curva de saturação do TC simulado;
\ditem[5em]{burden} vetor linha ($2 \times 1$) com a resistência e reatância do \textit{burden} do TC;
\ditem[5em]{ang}  vetor linha ($2 \times 1$) com os ângulos de incidência da $1^a$ e $2^a$ faltas;
\end{document}
```

Comment: yours response went out far beyond what i needed. Many thanks.